AzureML Data Labeling Project "Failed to submit one of the labels" when trying to convert a polygon to mask
I've set up a data labeling project for semantic segmentation. I want to start labeling my data but whenever I draw a polygon around part of the image and try to submit it, I get the following error:
"Failed to submit one of the labels
Service temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.
Trace ID: xyz Client Request ID: xyz"
-Tried closing and relaunching the AzureML-studio in hopes that that would fix it. It didn't.
-Tried waiting for a few hours but the error is still there.
-Tried labeling different data in another workspace that I've worked in previously. This worked so it could also be a permission-problem in the workspace
-Tried getting the "Data Labeling - Labeler" permission but the error persists

provide the sample data you trying to lable.

I can't add sample data since the data is confidential. It is just a regular .jpg in a blob storage. Nothing special about it.


Can you try labelling same data in different workspace and check
Also, check with different data in the current workspace.


To answer this, it was a problem with permissions.
The workspace was not automatically using my own permissions to access the storage and the workspace itself didn't have the necessary permissions to access the storage either. After giving the workspace the necessary permissions, it worked.
